# How can I filter the field so that when I select a category, only those products that belong to this category are displayed?

Tags: python, django, django-views

My models, category and product. Each product has a category field, which is linked through ForeignKey.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='category', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product', blank=True)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'products'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And views, a product category can be selected and when I click on a category, I want the product to appear only in that category

```
class CategoriesList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'login/'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    model = Category

class ProductsList(ListView):
    template_name = 'products.html'
    model = Product

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(category=category_id)
```

Comment: You can use query params and pass it on to the URL, which will be available in `self.request.GET` inside `get_queryset`